# How to implement a generic view presenter in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mvp

I am currently using [laracasts/Presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter) to handle logic related to my views, this implementation is connected to a model. But I also have some *generic view logic* that I would like to implement, what is the best practice for creating this?

I have tried two methods, but neither feels right:

- Custom class `ViewHelper` with static functions, called with `ViewHelper::Method`.
- Blade include files, called with `@include('includes.navicon')`

Is there a better way of doing this? Or is one (or both) of the above acceptable?

**Edit:** We're talking simple stuff here like insert page title, run text though Markdown parser. This is an example of a function that I use on all pages, it just creates and returns a page header.

```
public static function PageTitle($level, $title, $small = null)
{
    if ($small != null) $title = $title . " <small>" . $small . "</small>";

    $html = "<div class=\"page-header\" style=\"margin-top: 0px\"><h%1\$d>%2\$s</h%1\$d></div>";
    return sprintf($html, $level, $title);
}
```

The view presenter that I have installed makes use of the model, so to get a formatted URL for example I would use the command: `{{ $article->present()->url }}`, while this generic view logic should be available in all views without having to add it to all the models.

Comment: Can you provide use cases / examples for your generic view logic? Where/how they will be used and how they are different from the library you referred to

Comment: Question updated with example generic view logic and difference from the view presenter library.

Comment: Then how about using Laravel's View Composer? http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers You can pass the blade template you are using (or the layout base) to make sure the composer gets called each time and pass the variable along to your templates.

Comment: Good idea, haven't considered that. I'll experiment with it and report back, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a base class that all view presenters extend, and move everything generic there. Functions that is required on views that do not have a model I simply added as static.

**Model**, I added `$presenterInfo` to pass information to load the correct view(s) and use as a title prefix. The rest is required by the view presenter.

```
use Laracasts\Presenter\PresentableTrait;
...
use PresentableTrait;
protected $presenter = 'ArticlePresenter';
public $presenterInfo = ['view' =>'articles', 'category' => 'Article'];
```

**Baseclass**, everything generic goes here. So basically everything that might be useful on multiple classes and their views.

```
use Laracasts\Presenter\Presenter;

class BasePresenter extends Presenter {

    public static function pageHeader($level, $title, $small = null)
    {
        if ($small != null) $title .= " <small>" . $small . "</small>";

        $html = "<div class=\"page-header\" style=\"margin-top: 0px\"><h%1\$d>$this->presenterInfo['category']: %2\$s</h%1\$d></div>";
        return sprintf($html, $level, $title);
    }

    public function url()
    {
        return URL::route($this->presenterInfo['view'] . '.show', array('id' => $this->id, 'slug' => Str::slug($this->title)));
    }
}
```

**Viewclass**, functions that will only be available for the selected class; in this case `Article`.

```
class ArticlePresenter extends BasePresenter {

    // Example function only needed by the article class.
    public function stump()
    {
        return Str::limit($this->content, 500);
    }
}
```

**Examples**, loading view presenter data:

```
// Show page header level 2
{{ BasePresenter::pageHeader(2, 'Articles') }}

// Enumerate the articles and show title, stump and read more link
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <article>
        <h3>{{ HTML::link($article->present()->url, $article->title) }}</h3>
        <div class="body">
            <p>{{ $article->present()->stump }}</p>
            <p><a href="{{ $article->present()->url }}">Read more...</a>
        </div>
    </article>
@endforeach
```